# Using input to unique vector is not work in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use the input to select the variable in the dataframe and unique it to get a vector.

But it's not work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("variable", "Variable:",colnames(iris))
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            textOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$table <- renderText({
        
        a <- unique(iris$input$variable])
        
        
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[[` to subset the dataframe based on user input.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("variable", "Variable:",colnames(iris))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderText({
    a <- unique(iris[[input$variable]])
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```